# Create linked server and call it from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I got 2 database from different server(mydb_1 & mydb_2). So I want to create stored procedure inside **mydb_1** where it will be call table inside **mydb_2**.

To achieve this I create linked server in **mydb_1** using T-SQL in the visual studio. I can create this linked server in the Microsft SQL Management Studio, but I want to create it in the T-SQL because of stored procedure. Do you guys have any suggestion to achieve this? Below is my code I create based on this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql#g-add-a-includesssdsfullincludessssdsfull-mdmd-as-a-linked-server-for-use-with-distributed-queries-on-cloud-and-on-premise-databases)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureTest_1]
@param varchar = 'Info'
AS

BEGIN
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver  
    @server = 'myLinkedServer',
    @srvproduct = '',       
    @provider = 'sqlncli',
    @datasrc = '192.168.1.203', 
    @location = '',  
    @provstr = '',  
    @catalog = 'mydb_2'


EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin  
    @rmtsrvname = 'myLinkedServer',  
    @useself = 'false',  
    @rmtuser = 'username',             
    @rmtpassword = 'password'

SELECT * FROM myLinkedServer.mydb_2.dbo.userActivity WHERE Level = @param
END

GO
```

My connection string inside web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="mydb_1_connection" connectionString="Data Source=mySUPPORT13;Initial Catalog=mydb_1;User ID=mydb_1_username;Password=mydb_1_password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="mydb_2_connection" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.203;Initial Catalog=mydb_2;User ID=mydb_2_username;Password=mydb_2_password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

By using the code above, I can create stored procedure but not linked server.

Comment: Do you get any errors from running the stored procedure you've created?

Comment: Nope, didn't get any error. Did my code is correct to create it. I'm newbie here.

Comment: Well, you've created a stored procedure that it will do 3 things: 1) Link a server 2) Add a login 3) Select data from the other server. Is that what you intended to do? The link won't be created automatically unless you run the procedure. I don't think you need to do it for _every_ call, as it appears you are here.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use! Here, by defining `@param varchar`, you get **exactly *ONE* character of length** - probably *not* what you wanted, right?? ***ALWAYS*** define explicit length in your `varchar` definitions!